# C# .NET Searching text across hard returns

Tags: c#, .net, search, richtextbox, carriage-return

Since I have not been able to find an resolution via my searching endeavor, I believe I may have a unique problem. Essentially I am creating a gene finding/creation application in c#.NET for my wife and am using RichTextBoxes for her to be able to highlight, color, export, etc the information she needs. I have made several custom methods for it because, as I am sure we all know, RichTextBoxes from Microsoft leave much to the imagination.

Anyway, here is my issue: I need to be able to search for a term across hard returns. The users have strings in 60 letter intervals and they need to search for items that may cross that hard return barrier. For instance let's say I have 2 lines (I will make them short for simplicity):
AAATTTCCCGGG
TTTCCCGGGAAA

If the user runs a search for GGGTTT, I need to be able to pull the result even though there is a line break/hard return in there. For the life of me I cannot think of a good way to do this and still select the result in the RichTextBox. I can always find the result but getting a proper index for the RichTextBox is what eludes me.

If needed I am not against richTextBox.SaveFile() and LoadFile() and parsing the rtf text as a string manually. It doesnt have to be pretty, in this case, it just has to work.

I  appreciate any help/guidance you may give.

Here is a relevant snippet:

```
        //textbox 2 search area (examination area)
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.ToUpper();
        if (textBox3.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            List<string> lines = richTextBox2.Lines.ToList();
            string allText = "";
            foreach (string line in lines)
                allText = allText + line.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
            if (findMultiLineRTB2(allText, textBox3.Text) != -1)
            {
                richTextBox2.Select(lastMatchForRTB2, textBox3.Text.Length);
                richTextBox2.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                richTextBox2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            }//end if
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Reached the end of the sequence", "Finished Searching");
        }//end if
    }//end method

    private int findMultiLineRTB2(string rtbText, string searchString)
    {
        lastMatchForRTB2 = rtbText.IndexOf(searchString, lastMatchForRTB2 + 1);
        return lastMatchForRTB2;
    }
```

Comment: So every line in the `TextBox` is 60 characters long and you want to search across all lines? What would be the desired result, the first or the second line or even both lines?

Comment: You need to get the word index? or line?

Comment: Only a comment but consider a FlowDocument.  You actually mark up the content rather than highlight by position in the RTB.

Answer (score 1):

So i make an assumption: you want to search a word across all lines where each line is 60 characters long. The desired result is the index of that word.

You just have to build a string that has no line breaks, for example with `string.Join`:

```
string allText = string.Join("", richTextBox.Lines);
int indexOf = allText.IndexOf("GGGTTT");  // 9 in your sample
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! However, the hard returns are causing 2 issues. The beginning of the index is going to be one off for every line in the RichTextBox. Apparently the hard returns are counted as part of the index for the result but placing them in one large string does not. Also if the results go across hard returns, for each hard return, the selected result will be one letter short because the richTextBox counts the hard return as a character and the single string does not. Any ideas? I added my relevant code if needed.